# UK visa passport validity

Tags: visas, uk, passports

I have a EEA UK visa valid for 2 more years, but my passport will expire in 3 months. Now I am returning from holiday back to the UK. Can I travel back as my passport has only 3 months validity?

Comment: What is your nationality, where are you normally resident, and are you quite sure you have an "*EEA UK visa*"?

Comment: VTC: not possible to accurately respond, as OP has not returned to clarify as requested (and as there is not an *EEA UK visa*).